# Selenium Script executes very slow in IE10 in a 64 bit machine,while entering text in text boxes

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

Selenium Script executes very slow in IE10 in a 64 bit machine, while entering text in text boxes, takes 3 to 4 secs between each character. Works fine in IE 10 in a 32 bit machine,also works fine in IE 9 in 64 bit machine. So the issue is specific with IE 10 in 64 bit OS.

Can someone help me out on this, also please share your views who has come across the same situation

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5116

Answer (score 0):

To be even more specific, the issue is unique to 64-bit IE 10 or higher. Running 32-bit IE, even on a 64-bit OS, does not exhibit the problem. Additionally, it should be noted that the vast majority of your users will be using 32-bit IE, even if they're using 64-bit Windows.

The root cause of the issue is clearly spelled out in [one of the issue comments](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5116#c16). It's an interaction problem between IE and the driver. Absent someone debugging the issue and submitting a patch/pull request, how, exactly, would you expect someone to be able to "help [you] out with this?"

As a workaround, you could try two things. You could turn off native events, or you could set the `requireWindowFocus` capability. Both of these use different methods to simulate user input. More information can be found in [this blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html).